# Zip file sent with perl Email::Sender is corrupted

Tags: perl, smtp, zip, email-attachments

I'm trying to run a script that takes a text file, compresses it using Archive::Zip, and sends the zip file as an attachment via smtp using Email::Sender to create a mime message.

I can send txt files in perl without corruption.  I can send the file that perl zips manually without corruption.  I can not send a manually zipped file through perl.

I suspect my problem is with either reading the zipped file, or creating the MIME message.  Here is the relevant code, which is essentially the code from the synopsis of Email::MIME, where $fileToSend is the path to the zipped file.

Any ideas?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::MIME;
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);
use IO::All;

my $message = 
      Email::MIME->create(
      header_str => [
    From    => $sender,
    To      => $recipient,
    Subject => $subject,
  ],
          attributes => {
              filename     => $filename,
              content_type => 'application/zip',
              disposition  => 'attachment',
              name         => $filename,
          },
          body => io($fileToSend)->binary->all,
          #body => io($fileToSend)->all,
      );
```

Comment: What's the difference between the sent and received files?

Comment: The recieved zip file is slightly smaller than the sent zipped (822 kb vs 893 kb).  That's why I suspect io() to be the problem.

Comment: why this complex method, just send file as attachment?

Comment: @netawater - feel free to add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem finally.  Adding this line did the trick.

```
$message->encoding_set( 'base64' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
                   host => $smtpserver,
                   port => $smtpport,
                   sasl_username => $smtpuser,
                   sasl_password => $smtppassword,
                   ssl => 'starttls'});

Email::Stuffer->from('a@a.com')
          ->to('b@b.com')
          ->text_body('hello')
          ->attach_file ('zipfile')
          ->transport($transport)
          ->send();
```